# Items are hidden from RecyclerView after update till user scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a fragment [DISPLAY SCREEN] with RecyclerView After user click on item of it, app open screen [EDIT SCREEN] to allow user edit that itme.
when user finish update i close fragment [EDIT SCREEN] and back to [DISPLAY SCREEN] and make new request to api to get data again

i checked thread of update method which accept data from **api** and thread was **main**

```
  private fun updateScreen(data: List<GymPackage>) {
    "updateScreen size ${data.size} pageNumber $pageNumber , thread num ${Thread.currentThread().name}".log(mTag)

    if (pageNumber++ == 1)
        packagesAdapter.clear()

    packagesAdapter.append(data)

    ("updateScreen size ${data.size} pageNumber $pageNumber ,, adapter ${packagesAdapter.itemCount}, ${packagesAdapter.getItemViewType(0)}" +
            ",${(packagesRecyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()}").log(mTag)
    /**
     * after get first page sometimes items not being shown so scroll to first item
     */

    packagesRecyclerView.scrollBy(0 , 50)


    loadMore = data.size == pageSize
    packagesAdapter.loadingProgressBar = data.size == pageSize

    tvNoData?.visibility = (packagesAdapter.itemCount == 0).gotViewVisiblity(true)
}
```

Output:

[image]

first two lines are with when [DISPLAY SCREEN] get list of items,

- thread is main
- n items inside adapter of RecyclerView -> 5
- 0 is index of first visible item in RecyclerView

second two lines after return from [EDIT SCREEN]

- thread is main
- n items inside adapter of RecyclerView -> 5
- -1 is index of first visible item in RecyclerView --> so user do not see any items

when user scroll he sees items normally.

I tried to make rv scroll using

`packagesRecyclerView.scrollBy(0 , 50)`

also

`packagesRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)`

both with no results

## Update 1

tried these

- packagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
- packagesRecyclerView.performClick()

with no results

## Update 2

with beta7 Google said it provides fixes to

- Nested scroll view issues in MotionLayout
- Transition listener issues with MotionLayout
- Memory leak in MotionLayout
- RecyclerView performances
- Group visibility
- Padding issues

after I update lib to, app works fine, but motion has other issues with padding

```
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta7'
```

Comment: So, the mentioned problem is solved by updating to ```beta7```, but you got new bugs?

Comment: yes, but motion has some issues with padding of some items

Comment: If u think its motion related, you can try other versions. ```beta7``` causes app crashes for me, ```beta6``` has some transition bugs, so Im currently sitting on ```beta4```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return to beta4

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
```

and use

```
   motion.transitionToStart()
```